# Menu vertical sumindo por baixo do rodapé

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Em telas onde a altura é menor que 600px o menu passa a sumir por baixo do rodapé.
Também tentei deixar a `position` como `fixed`, `relative` e sem nada porém o resultado foi o mesmo.

Segue o html do menu:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm " id="menuwraper">
    <div id="menu" class="hidden-xs ">
        <ul id="navegacao">
            <li>
                <a href="home"><img src="imagensite/logo.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="efeito"><a href="sobre">SOBRE NÓS</a></li>
            <li class="efeito"><a href="projetos">PROJETOS</a></li>
            <li class="efeito"><a href="noticias">NOVIDADES</a></li>
            <li class="efeito"><a href="contato">CONTATO</a></li>
            <li class="efeito"><a href="parceiros">PARCEIROS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

O css:

```
#menu {
  height: 400px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:31px;
  width: 15%;
  margin-bottom:140px;
}
```

Uma imagem do que está acontecendo:

<kbd>[image: imagem]</kbd>

Como vocês podem vero "parceiros" está embaixo do rodapé.

Comment: Você está usando pixels nos comandos eles geralmente não se adaptam a diferentes resoluções, tente usar porcentagem.

Comment: Tentei isso porém continua acontecendo o mesmo,queria deixar o position como fixed...

Comment: Você quer apenas redimensionar o menu ou que ele fique acima do rodapé?

Comment: Redimensionar..

Comment: Coloca no MENU `z-index: 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Deixe o rodapé e o menu com altura em porcentagem, isso fará com que funcione independente da resolução da tela.

Caso a página não vá ter scroll, ambos os elementos podem ter `position:absolute;`, ai é só colocar um `bottom:0;` pro rodapé, senão pode manter o rodapé com `position:fixed;`, para isso coloquei o `z-index` no exemplo, que fará com que o menu se sobreponha ao rodapé.

Obs. Quanto maior o valor de `z-index`, maior a "camada" que o elemento ficará.

```css
#menu {
  height: 90%; /*Pode ser outro valor, esse é só um exemplo*/
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:31px;
  width: 15%;
  margin-bottom:140px;
  z-index:5000; /*Isso é para que ele se sobreponha ao rodape caso necessario*/
}
```

Como usei `height: 90%;` no menu, o rodapé deveria ficar com `height: 10%;`, ou menos, para que tudo funcione.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma porém mesmo assim ele continua desaparecendo,não tem uma forma de que apareça uma barra de rolagem na lateral para mostrar ele?Assim como acontece com o contéudo...

Comment: Só uma pergunta, a página precisa ser sem scroll?

Comment: acabei de checar e realmente o erro continua. Para solucionar, mantenha o código que mandei e acrescente ao menu a propriedade `overflow:auto`, dessa forma ele mostrará a barra de rolagem somente quando necessário, se precisar mando exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez pode dar certo colocar da seguinte forma:

```
#menu { position:absolute; height:0; width: 15%; top: auto; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: auto; margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom:5%; padding-bottom: 30%; ( aumenta até achar a altura certa ) }
```

Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo as dicas apresentadas nessa pergunta consegui resolver meu problema com o seguinte código:

```
margin-top:30px;
width: 15%;
position:absolute;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 10%;
padding-bottom: 3%;
```

Grato a todos que ajudaram!